# Error 500 in API Call with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Datafactory to get data from a REST API. The API call works fine for a while, but ends up with the following error message:

{"httpStatusCode":500,"type":"InternalSystemError","details":[{"message":"Internal Server Error","location":null}]}},Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Does anyone know what the problem is or how to fix this?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Error 500 is a server side error. Well programmed servers are supposed to tell you, if they received bad parameters. Are you calling the API with identical parameters each time or is it a specific set of parameters that causes the crash?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Azure Data Lake does emit HTTP/500 occasionally.. As described in multiple comments and answers, the problem is at server side and there isn't much to do besides retry later.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500, Internal Server Error can occur due to many reasons. Here are a few error sources.

- Error occurs due to intermittent/transient issues.
- Error occurred in the configuration of the webserver.
- Error occurs due to permissions issues at client-server.
- Error occurs due to time out.

If the issue is not resolved yet or you still experience the issue consistently, I would recommend raising a support ticket for the support engineer to investigate.